# Combining Aquamacs (editing buffer and speedbar) and Skim into one window

Tags: screen

Is it possible to combine Aquamacs editing buffer and the speedbar with Skim in one window? If possible, I would like to be able to open all three windows from one button on an Apple macbook using OSX Yosemite 10.10.3.

Comment: Vaguely related:  In case it's not possible, you might like to try using [spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) to get Skim and your editor open side by side and maximised.  It's free and open source.  Caveat: I've only just started using it.

Comment: Thruston - thanks. I downloaded spectacle - interesting but now what I need unfortunately. I need to be able to click on a button on the 'Quick Launch' bar in OSX which open the three windows.  Mike

Comment: You might get more Apple specific help over at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For the opening thing: you could create an application with automator, which opens all your programms